# Using both Apache Airflow and Github Actions for dBT

Tags: continuous-integration, airflow, github-actions, cicd, dbt

I'm trying to get my head around if replacing our current CI/CD tool with Github Actions is a pro or con.

My team is currently using GitHub and TeamCity for CI/CD. I find this limiting as it's a separate team that configures the different stages. We use Airflow to schedule our DBT production, so we don't use DBT Cloud.

I'm wondering if there's any benefit to replacing TeamCity with Github Actions as we can write the configuration of the stages (compile, run, test, lint) ourselves. I'm interested in implementing Slim CI , which I don't believe is possible with TeamCity.

Would anyone be able to with the pros and cons of using GitHub Actions alongside Airflow? Is it possible? I'm struggling to find any documentation on using both Actions whilst running DBT production on Airflow.

Right now, my source of information comes from this: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-dbt-to-production-using-github-action-778bf6a1dff6

It mentions *"Well, it depends. If you don’t have Airflow running in productions already, you will probably not need it now. There are more simple/elegant solutions than this (dbt Cloud, GitHub Actions, GitLab CI). Also, this approach shares many disadvantages with using a compute instance, such as waste of resources and no easy way for CI/CD."*

My main goal is to get rid of TeamCity and implement Slim CI with Github Actions.

Thank you in advance!